# How do I install Windows on a Chromebook Samsung 550C (Lumpy)?

Tags: windows, chromebook

How do I install Windows on a Samsung 550C?

Samsung has new 120GB SSD.

I used a SATA to eSATA converter.

Then I installed Windows on a PC through the converter, and then I put the drive into the Chromebook.

Chrome OS is not working.

I created a bootable USB from application Google for my type (Lumpy Orange A-C 1248).

Recovery was OK, then I removed the USB, rebooted the system,  and then the same problem (use the recovery USB ).

I don't know where is the problem.

I can not set up boot selection (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> not working).

I will be grateful for any ideas for how I can install Windows.

Comment: Its a bit more complicated that that...http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-install-windows-chromebook/

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I tried all possibilities. Chrome OS, I can not install it .... windows is impossible ... This Chromebook is fascinating. I did not expect such problems, I'm disappointed. I switched jumper for developed mode, it still does not work. I would only boot menu, where I chose booting the operating system from a USB, but it is impossible. :(

Comment: Let us know if you ever find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

i have your same chromebook and i think you can't install windows because:

> Legacy Boot
>
> Sorry, but this device does not support a legacy BIOS mode. It
>   predates the launch of that feature and it is not feasible to produce
>   updates of devices in the field.

I find this information here:
https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/developer-information-for-chrome-os-devices/samsung-sandy-bridge

Please let me know if you find anoter way, or i miss something.

:)